# Error al enviar datos de formulario a base de datos php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

soy novato en el tema de programación, estoy intentando enviar los datos que se ponen en el formulario hacia una base de datos, he estado practicando por ahora con este sencillo que he descargado, sin embargo, los datos no se envían, solo logré un registro existoso, pero ahora ya no sé porque no se ejecuta correctamente. No sé si el error pueda estar en el Mysqli, aunque veo que la conexión con el servidor está bien, he verificado el código php y aparentemente está correcta la sintaxis.
También lo he intentado creando dos archivos php, uno para el registro de los datos y otro con el enlace hacia el servidor y aún así sigue lanzando error, en este mismo foro ví que posiblemente podía descubrir el error usando unas líneas de php, pero tampoco logro descubrirlo, de antemano Agradezco si me pueden echar una mano.

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $clave="";
    $baseDedatos="formulario1";

$enlace=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave,$baseDedatos);

if(!$enlace){
    echo "error en la conexion con el servidor";
}
    
    

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Formulario De Registro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <form action="#" class="formulario" id="formulario" name="formulario" method="POST">
            <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Correo">

                <div class="sexo">
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="hombre" value="hombre">
                    <label class="label-radio hombre" for="hombre">Hombre</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="mujer" value="mujer">
                    <label class="label-radio mujer" for="mujer">Mujer</label>
                </div>

                <div class="terminos">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos">
                    <label for="terminos">Acepto Terminos y Condiciones</label>
                </div>

                <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="registrarse" value="Registrate">
        </form>
        
    </div>
    <script src="formulario.js"></script>
        
</body>
</html>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['registrarse'])){
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
        $correo=$_POST["correo"];
        $sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
       
       $insertardatos="INSERT INTO reg_db VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$sexo')";
       
       $ejecutarInsertar= mysqli_query($enlace, $insertardatos);
       
       if(!$ejecutarInsertar){
           echo"¡Máldito error!";
       }
       
}
?>
```

[image: base de datos Phpmyadmin]

[image: log errores]

Comment: ¿En la tabla `reg_db` solamente tienes esos 3 campos o tienes algun id?

Comment: Comparte el esquema de la base de datos

Comment: Saludos, Pon a todos los elemento (que lo permitan) su `id` y que sea el mismo de `name`; asi mismo pon los campos que se afectaran en el mismo orden que los datos en `values` que se ingresan (salvo estén en el mismo orden que los colocas). Como no especificas algún error; prueba revisando el `log`de PHP por si hay alguno y no tienes como salida el php donde ocurre.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, @JosueArriola, también tengo un Id, comparto imagen de base de datos

Comment: @Joel Muñoz, comparto captura de la base de datos

Comment: @RobertoLeOr agradezco por tu respuesta, he colocado una captura con parte del archivo error.log a ver si ayuda a reconocer el error, pues a simple vista no entiendo mucho todos esos caracteres...

Comment: @JOHNWILCHES el log es ascendente; lo que se necesita son las últimas líneas (pusiste las primeras) esto desde luego despues de ejecutar el php donde se presenta la situación de la que requieres apoyo. Prueba agregando al sql `INSERT` seguido de `reg_db` los campos que proporcionas valor (abajo en respuesta un usuario lo puso).

Answer (score 0):

para insertar, se hace con la expresion

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col) VALUES(value);
```

en donde tbl_name es el nombre de la tabla, col es el nombre de la columna y value el valor a insertar en esa columna.

```
$insertardatos="INSERT INTO reg_db VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$sexo')";
```

En esta parte del codigo no declaras en que columna se insertara el valor correspondiente. Podrias modificarlo a:

```
$insertardatos="INSERT INTO reg_db (col_nombre, col_correo, col_sexo) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$sexo')";
```

Donde col_nombre sera el nombre de tu culumna para ese valor, asi como col_correo y col_sexo

Comment: Gracias, he hecho lo siguiente: dentro de la base de datos eliminé la columna ID, nuevamente intenté hacer el registro y funcionó, aparece el registro en la base de datos con los tres campos (Nombre, Correo y Sexo).